# AngularJS watch json periodically

Tags: json, angularjs, watch

I try to get a json file via $http by calling a DataService periodically.

Then I want to use the $watch functionality to react to any data change. However the watch function never gets triggered more than once. Why?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        //...
    }])

    .

    run(function ($rootScope, $timeout, $location, DataService) {

        $rootScope.jsonData = {}

        var delaytime = 10 * 1000;

        $rootScope.jsonData = DataService.getData();

        $timeout(function repeat() {
                console.log("in repeat")
                $rootScope.jsonData = DataService.getData();
                $timeout(function () {
                        console.log("in inner repeat")
                        repeat();
                    }, delaytime
                );
            }, delaytime
        );



        console.log("xxx")
        console.log($rootScope.jsonData)
        $rootScope.$watch('jsonData', reactToDataChange($rootScope, $location));
    })


;


function reactToDataChange($rootScope, $location) {
    console.log("yyy")
    console.log($rootScope.jsonData)
    // ...
}
```

DataService:

```
app.service('DataService', function ($http) {

var data = null;

function setData(newdata) {
    data = newdata;
}

return {

    getData: function () {

        console.log("getting data");

        var rand = "?rand=" + Math.random() * 10000;
        $http.get('data/bla.json' + rand, {cache: false})

            .success(function (newdata) {
                console.log(newdata);
                setData(newdata);
            })
            .

            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(status)
            });


        return data;
    }
};
});
```

Console shows:

```
getting data 
xxx
null
yyy
null
new data:[object Object]
Object {bla: Object}
in repeat
getting data
new data:[object Object]
Object {bla: Object}
in inner repeat
in repeat
getting data
new data:[object Object]
Object {bla: Object}
in inner repeat
in repeat
...
```

Why is yyy not shown again?

Comment: I can't see definition of `getData()` in your DataService and I'm wondering how it works at all. Shouldn't it have `getData: function(){ /* contents of current return */ }` inside `return` in DataService?

Comment: sorry somehow the inner function declaration was deleted by me when I edited the code for the question. Now updated version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to your "Why?" is that $watch takes a **function** as a second parameter while you're passing `reactToDataChange($rootScope,$location)` which is a function call and returns `undefined`. It's easy to fix it by modifying `reactToDataChange`:

```
function reactToDataChange($rootScope, $location) {
    return function(){
        console.log("yyy")
        console.log($rootScope.jsonData)
        // ...
    }
}
```

By the way your repeat is overcomplicated. Why not try this:

```
var rep = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $rootScope.jsonData = DataService.getData();
        rep();
    },delaytime);
}
rep();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rootScope.$watch('jsonData', reactToDataChange($rootScope, $location), true);
```

Comment: does not change anything. Even if I change the bla.json at some point of the run

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
function reactToDataChange($rootScope, $location) {
    console.log("yyy")
    console.log($rootScope.jsonData)
}
```

to

```
function reactToDataChange($rootScope, $location) {
    return function(){
        console.log("yyy")
        console.log($rootScope.jsonData)
    }
}
```

You should apply `true` as third argument for $watch to start "deep watching" of jsonData object:

```
$rootScope.$watch('jsonData', reactToDataChange($rootScope, $location), true);
```

And you can access new value of jsonData without passing rootScope to callback, just use first argument:

```
$rootScope.$watch('jsonData', reactToDataChange, true);
....
function reactToDataChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the improvements of the code. They don't seem to fix my problem though.